# Jquery when done not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am stuck at a place.
What i want to do is that I 2 functions and both of them run asynchronously. So i found about the when done of jquery and thought to use that.

See below for my code that i am using:-

```
 $.when(doOne(42, PersonId))
.done(function (strDisplayMessage) {
    doTwo()
})


function doOne(systemMessageId, personId) {
    /* This function is used to make an AJAX call to the backend function to get all the customized system message. */
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/Communications/GetSpecifiedSystemMessageAndCustomizeIt",
        type: "POST",
        data: { intSystemMessageId: systemMessageId, guidPersonId: personId },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
return data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            return "Error!";
        }
    });
}

function doTwo(){
...//do something
}
```

But they still run asynchronously.
Can anybody help me with this?

Thanx

Answer (score 5):

You need to return the ajax object from `doOne`

```
$.when(doOne(42, PersonId))
.done(function (strDisplayMessage) {
    doTwo()
})


function doOne(systemMessageId, personId) {
    /* This function is used to make an AJAX call to the backend function to get all the customized system message. */
   return $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Communications/GetSpecifiedSystemMessageAndCustomizeIt",
            type: "POST",
            data: { intSystemMessageId: systemMessageId, guidPersonId: personId },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                return "Error!";
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the result of`$.ajax` in the `doOne` function:

```
function doOne(...) {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

Without the explicit `return` the function returns `undefined` to `$.when()` which will cause it to trigger the `.done` handler immediately.